# Problem trying to install microsoft botbuilder package

Tags: package, installation, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am following this tutorial on how to add a QnA Maker to a Microsoft Botframework template in c#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-add-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

I am having a problem completing the step to install the packages needed to integrate the qna part.
In the tutorial it says to enter "dotnet add package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA" into the terminal

but when I do this i get the error:  **"Projet introuvable dans 'C:\Users\cclements3\'."**

(translation: **cannot find project in C:\Users\cclements3**)

I'm really stuck, I don't know what this could be.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going by the above error, is your project located in the directory you are trying to add the package? Are you on the root directory of your project in the terminal?

Comment: Silly question that I solved 5 mins after posting, I just had to navigate in the terminal, into the directory where my cs project was stored, then it worked fine. And on to the next set of problems!